# string array to data frame conversion in r

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have got this array in a string variable (k) and would like to convert it to a dataframe in r. The as.array(k) does not convert it. What is the best way to do this. Also, considering that there will be nested arrays in the future to be dealt with.

```
places = [[\"Abtenau\", \"Abtenau\", 767, 52, 3.0000],[\"Achenkirch\", \"Achenkirch am Achensee\", 248, 61, 6.0000],[\"Adelharz\", \"Adelharz\", 47, 46, 2.0000],[\"Alpbach\", \"Alpbachtal\", 2629, 89, 2.0000]]
```

Comment: consider the grey content as a string variable. How can i transform it to a dataframe with 4 rows and 5 columns containing the data.

Comment: yes, it does include it

Comment: oke, i did dput it

Comment: May be you need `library(jsonlite);as.data.frame(fromJSON(places))` or after retyping `library(hablar);library(dplyr); fromJSON(places) %>% as.data.frame %>% retype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be `jsonlite` to convert to a `matrix`, then change it to `data.frame` and `retype`

```
library(jsonlite)
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)
fromJSON(places) %>% 
     as.data.frame %>% 
     retype
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  V1         V2                        V3    V4    V5
#  <chr>      <chr>                  <int> <int> <int>
#1 Abtenau    Abtenau                  767    52     3
#2 Achenkirch Achenkirch am Achensee   248    61     6
#3 Adelharz   Adelharz                  47    46     2
#4 Alpbach    Alpbachtal              2629    89     2
```

---

Or this can be done with `base R` after removing the square brackets with regex

```
read.csv(text = gsub('[][]|"', "", gsub("(?<=\\]),(?=\\[)", "\n",
  places, perl = TRUE)), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#          V1                      V2   V3 V4 V5
#1    Abtenau                 Abtenau  767 52  3
#2 Achenkirch  Achenkirch am Achensee  248 61  6
#3   Adelharz                Adelharz   47 46  2
#4    Alpbach              Alpbachtal 2629 89  2
```

#### data

```
places <- "[[\"Abtenau\", \"Abtenau\", 767, 52, 3.0000],[\"Achenkirch\", \"Achenkirch am Achensee\", 248, 61, 6.0000],[\"Adelharz\", \"Adelharz\", 47, 46, 2.0000],[\"Alpbach\", \"Alpbachtal\", 2629, 89, 2.0000]]"
```

Comment: Could there be a way to combine `read.table` and `chartr` to achieve the same?